# lighttpd and AngularJS html5 mode

Tags: angularjs, html, url-rewriting, lighttpd, mode

I have an angularJS web in a lighttpd server, but the html5 mode doesn't work (error 404) when i refresh or do a direct link. I have my local server running Apache and there is no problem with the rewrite expression in the .htaccess.
This is the Apache code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  #Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule !\.\w+$ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

and this is the content of the lighttpd.conf

```
server.modules = (
        "mod_access",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_compress",
        "mod_redirect",
        "mod_rewrite",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www/html"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 80


index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html", "index.lighttpd.html$
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ( "application/javascript", "text/css", "text/htm$

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"

$HTTP["host"] == "myweb.io" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/html/"
    url.rewrite-once = ( "!\.\w+$" => "/index.html" )
}
```

I have searched all the internet and i haven't found anything about this. I don't know if i have not written well the regex or i put it in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

Simply setting the following did the trick for me: (no need for mod_rewrite)

```
server.error-handler-404 = "/index.html"
```

However, be wary of apparent bugs in older versions as noted in the [docs](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Server_error-handler-404Details).

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "(?!\.\w+$)" => "/index.html" )
```

Reference: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modrewrite

Alternatively, put the test in a conditional block

```
$HTTP["url"] !~ "\.\w+$" {
    url.rewrite-once = ( ".*" => "/index.html" )
}
```

Reference: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_Configuration

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
Solved with that:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = ( "(?!\.\w+$)" => "/index.html" )
```

References: https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modrewrite#urlrewrite-repeat-if-not-file